# Search and replace a sequence inside bracket

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file in which there is a line

```
byte address[] = { 0x54, 0x36, 0x45 };
```

I am trying to change the file by 3 command line parameters provided by the user -

```
grep byte | sed 's/\{.*\}/{ 0x$1, 0x$2, 0x$3 }/g' file.c
```

but no success.

The command used is -

```
sh script.sh 44 33 22
```

O/P -

```
byte address[] = { 0x44, 0x33, 0x22 };
```

Any help using `sed/awk` will be great!

Comment: show parameters values and desired result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest please see the edit

Comment: variables should be enclosed with double quotes

Comment: Ok `grep byte | sed 's/\{.*\}/{ 0x'$1', 0x'$2', 0x'$3' }/g' file.c` is working for me but the process in not ending and I have to using `Ctrl+C` to quit. Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: You just have a typo. Change `grep byte |` to `grep byte file.c |` and remove the `file.c` argument you're giving to sed.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I changed the to `grep byte file.c` but then it said that no file supplied to `sed`. So my final line that is now working is `grep byte file.c | sed 's/\{.*\}/{ 0x'$1', 0x'$2', 0x'$3' }/g' file.c` but this seems suspicious. Can you tell me whether is it fine or I missed something or a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you paste in a comment the exact command line that makes sed print that error message?

Comment: `grep byte file.c | sed 's/\{.*\}/{ 0x'$1', 0x'$2', 0x'$3' }/g'`

Comment: Aside from the `\{ \}` that I didn't notice, I'm not sure why sed would be giving an error. Maybe the $1 $2 $3 had some whitespace in them. I should have recommended putting the arg to sed in double quotes instead of single quotes. Anyway, glad you got a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to realize that the `\{` is special in `sed`. So you need this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename: yourscript.sh
# usage: ./yourscript.sh 44 33 22
for arg; do set "$@" " 0x$arg"; shift; done
IFS=",";
sed -e "/byte address\[\]/s/{[^}]*}/{$* }/"  yourfile.c
```

---

### Result

```
When invoked as:
%   ./yourscript.sh 44 33 22
byte address[] = { 0x44, 0x33, 0x22 };
```

---

### Explanation

1. First task is to obtain the `hexified` numbers from the arguments. This we get by looping over the arguments list using the `for` loop. Each time, we append the hex-version of the current argument at the end of the arguments list `$@` whilst at the same time taking away the current argument `shift` from the front of the list. So that means that at the end of the `for` loop iterations we would end up with the `hexified` arguments list.
2. Now we set the `IFS` to a comma for joining the arguments with a comma.
3. The sed code brings in the `"$*"` list inside the `sed` `s///` replacement part.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer, actually the parameters are 16 in number and I was looking for some looping method to implement this. It's just that in `byte address[] = { 0x54, 0x36, 0x45 };` the `0x54, 0x36, 0x45` is not fixed so couldn't use `echo`.

Comment: Just look at the `sed` code, it doesn't care how many hex are present in between the `{...}`. Just try the echo with your 16 hexes and give it a spin.

Comment: Works a charm! :)
A quick question, if you could tell me the significance of `shift` and `$*` here?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you may want to have a look.